# Typescript: RepositoryNotFoundError

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I try to save a single entity-type to a table using typeorm.
Sadly, if I run my tests against this code, I get

> RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "PayloadEntry" was found.
>   Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default"
>   connection?

The funny thing about that is I reused that code in another project where it works perfectly! So... how can I resolve that issue as it doesn't seem to make any sense.

This is, what my code looks like:

```
export const mysql_config : ConnectionOptions = {
    type: "mysql",
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    port: 3306,
    username: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PWD,
    database: "some_database",
    entities: [PayloadEntry],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false
};

createConnection(mysql_config).then(res => {
    console.log("Konfiguration erstellt!");
});

export module DatabaseAccess {

    export async function createPayload(payload : PayloadEntry) {
        try {
            let connection = await getConnection();
            let repo = connection.getRepository(PayloadEntry);
            return await repo.save(payload);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE PayloadEntry(
    payloadHash VARCHAR(256),
    serviceName VARCHAR(64),
    timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

And finally, the type definition:

```
@Entity('PayloadEntry')
export class PayloadEntry extends BaseEntity{

    constructor(payloadHash: string) {
        super();
        this.payloadHash = payloadHash;
    }

    @PrimaryColumn()
    payloadHash: string;

    @Column({nullable: true})
    serviceName?: string;

    @Column()
    timestamp : number = Date.now();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems just to be a timing error because mocha starts the tests before the connection is actually built completely.